# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Table collision when class name appears in different namespaces

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

When having two classes that has the same name, but in different namespaces, ServiceStacks OrmLite is unable to distinguish between the two. For example:

```js
Type type = typeof(FirstNameSpace.BaseModel);
using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.Open())
{
     db.CreateTable(false, type); // Creates table "basemodel"
}
                        
type = typeof(SecondNamespace.BaseModel);
using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.Open())
{
     db.CreateTable(false, type); // Creates nothing as there already is a table 'basemodel', even though its a completely different object/class
}
```

Is there a general, clean way to make sure that this is resolved?

It is not ideal to be forced to name classes uniquely; a part of the namespaces in .NET is to group and categorize different classes. Also, there might be third-party assemblies with the same class names, that is not available to change for you.

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OrmLite uses the name of the Type for the table name so you can’t use 2 different Types with the same name.

You will need to either rename one of the Types to avoid the collision or use the [Alias(“UseTableName”)] attribute to tell one of the Types to use a different RDBMS Table name.

Comment: If adding attributes they need to be done before any code is executed, otherwise you can update the ModelDefinition directly, e.g. `ModelDefinition<SecondNamespace.BaseModel>.Alias = "....";`

Comment: Right, thanks. For future reference: If you dont have access to the assembly code and its late-bound (like mine mostly are), then you can add the Alias attribute at Runtime, using something like: _Type type = typeof(SecondNamespace.BaseModel);
            type.AddAttributes(new AliasAttribute("SecondNamespaceBaseModel"));_